# replacing and moving values in list of list

Tags: python

I have following list of the list

```
[
    ['90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: 8.2/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', 'Studio Movie Grill - Downey', '11:15 am', '12:05 pm', '1:40', '2:30', '4:15', '6:40', '7:30', '9:05', '10:15'],
    ['90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: 8.2/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', 'AMC Norwalk 20', '11:45 am', '12:45 pm', '2:15', '3:15', '4:45', '5:45', '7:15', '8:15', '9:45', '10:45'],
    ['90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: 8.2/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', 'Cinemark Downey and XD', '10:00 am', '11:15', '12:30 pm', '1:45', '3:00', '4:15', '5:30', '6:30', '6:45', '8:00', '8:45', '9:15', '10:00', '10:30', '11:15', '11:45'],
    ['90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: 8.2/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', 'AMC Stonebriar 24', '11:40 am', '12:30 pm', '2:00', '3:00', '4:40', '5:30', '7:20', '8:00', '10:00', '10:30'],
    ['90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: 8.2/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', 'AMC Orange 30 (AMC Block 30)', '11:00 am', '12:15 pm', '1:30', '2:45', '4:00', '5:15', '6:30', '7:45', '9:00', '10:15']
]
```

I would like to do two things

1) If user rating ('User Rating: 8.2/10 (28,588 user ratings)') is >= 6.5, I would like to make it bold potentially by adding  tags around the existing value in list.
2) Secondly, I would like to move value after "Showtimes:" i.e. 10th element in the list of list and bring it to position "0"

I don't know how to do this, I am new to python. If somebody can give me the starting point I will appreciate that.

**Solution**

With help of solution provided by Ajax1234 below; I was able to write what I was looking for. This might not be the best solution but it works. The only improvement I have added from Ajax1234 solution is the position of "User Rating" and "Showtimes" are not hardcoded, they can be anywhere in the list.

```
import re
s = [['86 min', 'Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Fantasy', 'Mystery', 'Romance', 'User Rating: 4.7/10 (1,287 user ratings)', '36', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '75', 'Showtimes:', 'Studio Movie Grill - Downey', '11:00 am', '1:15 pm', '3:30', '5:45', '7:55'], ['86 min', 'Animation', 'Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Fantasy', 'Mystery', 'Romance', 'User Rating: 4.7/10 (1,287 user ratings)', '36', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '75', 'Showtimes:', 'AMC Norwalk 20', '11:35 am', '2:00 pm', '4:30', '7:00', '9:25']]


x1=''
a1=''
def getvalues(x,a):
    re_rating = re.compile('^User Rating: (\d(\.\d+)?)')
    for i, j in enumerate(s):
        for x,y in enumerate(j):
            if y == "Showtimes:":
                x1=x
        for a,b in enumerate(j):
            if re.match(re_rating, b):
                a1=a
    return x1,a1


x,a = getvalues(x1,a1)
print(x,a)
def fix_data(data,x,a):
    tags = ['<b>', '</b>']
    return [[i[x+1]]+i[:a]+[re.sub('(?<=User Rating: )[\d\.]+', '{}', i[a]).format((lambda x:tags[0]+x+tags[-1] if float(x) >= 6.5 else x)(re.findall('(?<=User Rating: )[\d\.]+', i[a])[0]))]+i[a+1:x+1]+i[x+2:] for i in data]

print(fix_data(s,x,a))
```

Comment: Could you tell us what you attempted and how it ended up? Have you tried iterating through the list, using indexes etc? Please edit your answer with any code you already have

Comment: for first thing, apply regex to extract out the string like `8.2/10` your_data[4], then convert this string to two number, finally get the rating. For second one, it is easy , just do like `item = [item[-1]]+item[0:-1]`

Comment: @necko I don't know even how to start, Ajax1234 was able to provide me the starting point. Now, I have the solution I was seeking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex and with a function to specify what type of "tags" should be used to surround the certain values:

```
import re
s = [['90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: 8.2/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', 'Studio Movie Grill - Downey', '11:15 am', '12:05 pm', '1:40', '2:30', '4:15', '6:40', '7:30', '9:05', '10:15'], ['90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: 8.2/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', 'AMC Norwalk 20', '11:45 am', '12:45 pm', '2:15', '3:15', '4:45', '5:45', '7:15', '8:15', '9:45', '10:45'],['90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: 8.2/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', 'Cinemark Downey and XD', '10:00 am', '11:15', '12:30 pm', '1:45', '3:00', '4:15', '5:30', '6:30', '6:45', '8:00', '8:45', '9:15', '10:00', '10:30', '11:15', '11:45'],['90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: 8.2/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', 'AMC Stonebriar 24', '11:40 am', '12:30 pm', '2:00', '3:00', '4:40', '5:30', '7:20', '8:00', '10:00', '10:30'], ['90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: 8.2/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', 'AMC Orange 30 (AMC Block 30)', '11:00 am', '12:15 pm', '1:30', '2:45', '4:00', '5:15', '6:30', '7:45', '9:00', '10:15']]
def fix_data(data, tags = ['[', ']']):
  return [[i[10]]+i[:4]+[re.sub('(?<=User Rating: )[\d\.]+', '{}', i[4]).format((lambda x:tags[0]+x+tags[-1] if float(x) >= 6.5 else x)(re.findall('(?<=User Rating: )[\d\.]+', i[4])[0]))]+i[5:10]+i[11:] for i in data]

print(fix_data(s, tags = ['<b>', '</b>']))
```

Output:

```
[['Studio Movie Grill - Downey', '90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: <b>8.2</b>/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', '11:15 am', '12:05 pm', '1:40', '2:30', '4:15', '6:40', '7:30', '9:05', '10:15'], ['AMC Norwalk 20', '90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: <b>8.2</b>/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', '11:45 am', '12:45 pm', '2:15', '3:15', '4:45', '5:45', '7:15', '8:15', '9:45', '10:45'], ['Cinemark Downey and XD', '90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: <b>8.2</b>/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', '10:00 am', '11:15', '12:30 pm', '1:45', '3:00', '4:15', '5:30', '6:30', '6:45', '8:00', '8:45', '9:15', '10:00', '10:30', '11:15', '11:45'], ['AMC Stonebriar 24', '90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: <b>8.2</b>/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', '11:40 am', '12:30 pm', '2:00', '3:00', '4:40', '5:30', '7:20', '8:00', '10:00', '10:30'], ['AMC Orange 30 (AMC Block 30)', '90 min', 'Drama', 'Horror', 'Thriller', 'User Rating: <b>8.2</b>/10 (28,588 user ratings)', '82', 'Metascore', 'Rank:', '2', 'Showtimes:', '11:00 am', '12:15 pm', '1:30', '2:45', '4:00', '5:15', '6:30', '7:45', '9:00', '10:15']]
```

Comment: thanks for looking into this, one problem is I would like to move value after Showtimes: to front for instance: in my example Studio Movie Grill - Downey

Comment: one more thing I have noticed you have placed [] around user rating can you changed it to <b></b>

Comment: @spider22 That can be done by simply changing the `tags` parameter when calling the function. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: ah, got it!! this is perfect

Comment: @spider22 Glad to help!

Comment: there is one problem the position of User Rating and Showtimes are moving based on the data from other movies. Can we use find to get position rather then hard coding ?

Comment: @spider22 Is there a specific pattern to their placement?